# Avoiding negative values

Tags: excel

In cell F44 I have:

`=IF(F42="N/A", "",IF(F42="Downgrade 2X", (F39-12), IF(F42="Downgrade", (F39-6), IF(F42="Upgrade", (F39+6), IF(F42="Upgrade 2X", (F39+12)))))))`

There is a number value in F39, F42 provides several options to upgrade (increase) or downgrade (decrease) that original value. Cell F45's alpha-value depends on the outcome of the formula in F44.

The problem I have is if my initial value in F39 is low enough, a further downgrade puts the value in F44 as negative. I don't want that. How do augment my formula above such that if the end result will be negative it is converted to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

around the outer IF statement add `MAX(0, ... )`